# React NPM packages to prevent, search and monitor places where state is mutated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, mutated

Do you know any worth recommending npm packages (for the DEV environment needs) to find spots in React app where redux store state is mutated ?

Currently I'm using Redux Freeze State package but unfortunatelly the indicated package is outdated, not supported any more and causes IE11 arguments caller exception.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-freeze-state

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import freezeState from 'redux-freeze-state';

let reducer = ...
let store = createStore(freezeState(reducer));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's several, and I have them listed in the Redux DevTools#Linting section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md#linting).

Listing those specifically:

- https://github.com/leoasis/redux-immutable-state-invariant
- https://github.com/jfpalacios/redux-freeze-state (the one you're using)
- https://github.com/buunguyen/redux-freeze
- https://github.com/tarodenberg/redux-freezer